# How can i change these into CTL SPEC in NuSMV model?

Tags: model, logic, model-checking, ctl, nusmv

I need help writing these CTL. I don't reall understand how to write in NuSMV format yet, hopefully my code will make sense to you since it is incomplete atm.

2)If a process is waiting, it will eventually get to its critical section

3)The two processes must 'take turns' entering the critical section

4)It is possible for one process to get into the critical section twice in     succession (before the other process does).

5)Successive entries into a critical section by process 1 will be separated by at least n cycles, where n is some constant. You should choose an appropriate value for n, and this one should be verified (i.e., not disproven).

6)2 more non-trivial properties of your choice

```
MODULE thread1(flag2,turn)
VAR
   state : {W0,F1,W1,T1,F2,Wait,F3,C1,T2,F4};
   flag1 : boolean;

ASSIGN
   init(state) := W0;
   next(state) :=
case
   state = W0                 : F1;  
   state = F1                 : W1;  
   state = W1 & flag2         : T1; 
   (state = W1) & !flag2      : C1;  
   (state = T1)&(turn = 2)    : F2;  
   (state = T1)&(turn != 2)   : W1;  
   (state = F2)               : Wait; 
   (state = Wait)&(turn = 1)  : F3;   
   (state = Wait)&(turn != 1) : Wait; 
   (state = F3)               : W1; 
   (state = C1)               : T2; 
   (state = T2)               : F4; 
   (state = F4)               : W0;
    TRUE : state;
esac;

init(flag1) := FALSE;
next(flag1) := 
case
   state = F1 | state = F3 : TRUE;  
   state = F2 | state = F4 : FALSE; 
   TRUE                    : flag1;
esac;

DEFINE
  critical := (state = C1);
  trying := (state = F1 | state = W1 | state = T1 | state = F2 |     state = Wait | state = F3);  

MODULE thread2(flag1,turn)
VAR
   state1 : {N0,N1,N2,N3,N4,Wait1,N5,Critical1,N7,N8};
   flag2 : boolean;

ASSIGN
   init(state1) := N0;
   next(state1) :=
case
   (state1 = N0)               : N1;  
   (state1 = N1)               : N2;  
   (state1 = N2) & flag1       : N3;  
   (state1 = N2) & !flag1      : Critical1;
   (state1 = N3) & (turn = 1)  : N4;  
   (state1 = N3) & (turn != 2) : N2;  
   (state1 = F4)               : Wait1; 
   (state1 = Wait1)&(turn = 2) : N5;   
   (state1 = Wait1)&(turn != 2): Wait1; 
   (state1 = N5)               : N2; 
   (state1 = Critical1)        : N7; 
   (state1 = N7)               : N8;
   (state1 = N8)               : N0;
    TRUE : state1;
esac;

init(flag2) := FALSE;
next(flag2) := 
case
   state1 = N1 | state1 = N5 : TRUE;  
   state1 = N4 | state1 = N8 : FALSE;
   TRUE                    : flag2;
esac;

DEFINE
  critical := (state1 = Critical1);
  trying := (state1 = N1 | state1 = N2 | state1 = N3 | state1 = N4 |     state1 = Wait1 | state1 = N5);  

MODULE main

VAR

turn: {1, 2};
proc1: process thread1(proc2.flag2,turn);
proc2: process thread2(proc1.flag1,turn);

ASSIGN

init(turn) := 1;
next(turn) := 
case
   proc1.state = T2 : 2;
   proc2.state1 = N7 : 1;
   TRUE : turn;
esac;

SPEC 

AG !(proc1.critical & proc2.critical); 
--two processes are never in the critical section at the same time

SPEC 
AG (proc1.trying -> AF proc1.critical);
```

Comment: The code doesn't truly work. I suggest you fix the code before thinking of writing the CTL formulas, because you need a consolidated model for it.

Comment: hmm yea i can't seem to figure out what the problem is whenever i run it it tells me line 88 "proc1.state" is undefined

Comment: Because there isn't a variable named state in thread1

Comment: hmmm okay so if i change it to proc1.state1        it then gives me the error proc2.state1    but i defined it as proc2.state tho

Comment: You could name both state, variables are local to the scope of the module they are in. I can't see the error you mention on the phone, on which line?

Comment: ooooo so i can just named them both state in the VAR and it won't cause a problem? in mod thread1 and thread2

Comment: it says line 73 proc2.state1 undefine in definition of proc2.trying at line 81

Comment: You need to fix all names. Could I *strongly* suggest you to take a look at the second link I posted in my answer to your previous question? it seems you could benefit from some course material.

Comment: hmmm yea i checked it out several times the model -checking of nusmv it has a great amount of details that i looked over i understand what A and E stands for A = every    E = exist       i just don't understand the other letter F , G ,.. and what kind of notation would i use for twice successful?

Comment: i figured out the problem! i got it to run without error!

Comment: **note:** edits are supposed to improve a question and to add any necessary clarification, not to change its scope and content. Your most recent edit completely invalidated the *accepted answer* and has thus been *rolled back*. You should open a new question if you have any other pending issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:** giving you a comprehensive introduction to **CTL** in an answer is quite unrealistic. In addition to [this](http://www.patricktrentin.com/pages/fm2018.html) quick and dirty course on NuSMV/nuXmv, you might benefit from looking at [these slides](http://disi.unitn.it/~rseba/DIDATTICA/fm2016/04_CTL_MODEL_CHECKING_SLIDES.pdf), which provide a theoretical background on CTL Model Checking.

---

**CTL OPERATORS**

Assume that for simplicity your program has a **unique** *initial state*.

The semantics of the **CTL** operators is the following:

- **AF P**: **in all** possible execution paths, **sooner or later** **P** will be *true*.
- **AG P**: **in all** possible execution paths, **P** is **always** *true*.
- **AX P**: **in all** possible execution paths, in the **next** state **P** is *true*.
- **A[P U Q]**: **in all** possible execution paths, **P** is *true* * **until** **Q** is *true* (at least once).
- **EF P**: **in at least one** execution path, **sooner or later** **P** will be *true*.
- **EG P**: **in at least one** execution path, **P** is **always** *true*.
- **EX P**: **in at least one** execution path, in the **next** state **P** is *true*.
- **E[P U Q]**: **in at least one** execution path, **P** is *true* * **until** **Q** is *true* (at least once).

*: **until** is *true* also on a path in which **P** is never *true*, provided that **Q** is immediately *verified*. [Also, see: [weak/strong until]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45729772/using-until-operator-in-spin-ltl-formula/45732502#45732502)

If you have **multiple** *initial states*, then the **CTL property** holds if it is *true* for every *initial state*.

[image: CTL operators]

---

**Properties:**

Note that since your *NuSMV* model is currently broken and this appears to be a homework, I will provide you with a **pseudo-code** version of the properties and leave it to you to fit them on your own code.

- if a process is waiting, then it will eventually get to its critical section

  ```
  CTLSPEC AG (proc1.waiting -> AF proc1.critical);
  ```

  **explanation:** the content of the parenthesis encodes exactly the sentence as you read it. I added **AG** because the property must clearly hold for every possible state in your model. If you omit it, then the model checker will simply test whether `proc1.waiting -> AF proc1.critical` is *true* in your initial state(s).
- the two processes must 'take turns' entering the critical section

  ```
  CTLSPEC AG ((proc1.critical -> AX A[!proc1.critical U proc2.critical]) &
             (proc2.critical -> AX A[!proc2.critical U proc1.critical]));
  ```

  **explanation:** let me premise that this encoding works because both *proc1* and *proc2* stay in the *critical section* for *only* one *state*. The idea of `proc1.critical -> AX A[!proc1.critical U proc2.critical]` is the following: *"if process 1 is in the critical section, then starting from the next state process 1 will never be in the critical section (again) until when process 2 is in the critical section"*.
- It is possible for one process to get into the critical section twice in succession (before the other process does).

  ```
  CTLSPEC EF (proc1.critical -> EX A[!proc2.critical U proc1.critical]);
  ```

  **explanation:** similar to the previous one. Here I use **EF** because it suffices the property *holds* just once.
- Successive entries into a critical section by process 1 will be separated by at least n cycles, where n is some constant. You should choose an appropriate value for n, and this one should be verified (i.e., not disproven).

  **edit:** I removed this encoding because on a second thought the formula I wrote is much *stronger* than required. However, I don't think it's possible to weaken it with the **E** operator, as it would become much *weaker* than required. At the time being I can't think of a possible alternative other than modify your model to count the number of *cycles*, whatever that means.

Comment: btw wheneven i try CTLSPEC it gives me an error, so i just write it with spec is there a difference?

Comment: @Darkflame what error do you get and what command do you use to check the property? -- note that I updated my answer

Comment: also another question is the "waiting" is one of the states correct just like  "critical" is also another state      ... in the semaphore example it had something like that was just curious if that is just a command or a state

Comment: nvm i think i fixed the CTLSPEC error cuz i had SPEC   and the CTL SPEC right after without putting anything in SPEC

Comment: @Darkflame I think that here *waiting* loosely corresponds to the *trying* label I put in my answer to your other question, so to a *set of states* rather than only one.