# Using (U)ntil operator in SPIN ltl formula

Tags: model-checking, spin, promela

I am trying to understand how to correctly use the Until operator in an ltl formula. I found [this](http://www.dis.uniroma1.it/~liberato/ar/ltl/ltl.html) definition (below) to be clear:

> **U**ntil
>
> A**U**B: true if there exists i such that:
>
> - B is true in [s<sub>i</sub>, s<sub>i+1</sub>, s<sub>i+2</sub>, …
>     ]
> - for all j such that 0 ≤ j < i, formula A is true in [s<sub>j</sub>, s<sub>j+1</sub>, s<sub>j+2</sub>,
>     … ]
>
> meaning:
>
> - B is true at time i
> - for times between 0 and i-1, formula A is true
>
> still using the formalization of "true at time i"

Sample code with example ltl formula:

```
mtype = {Regular, Reverse, Quit}

mtype state = Regular;

init {
do ::
   if
   ::state == Regular -> state = Reverse
   ::state == Reverse -> state = Quit
   ::state == Quit -> break
   fi
od
}

ltl p0 { [] ((state == Reverse) U (state != Reverse))}
```

Based on the definition of the until operator that I gave, I don't understand how the above ltl formula is not producing any errors. Wouldn't `state == Reverse` need to be true for all time up until `state != Reverse`? Initially `state == Regular`.

Below is the SPIN output after running the test:

```
(Spin Version 6.4.6 -- 2 December 2016)
    + Partial Order Reduction

Full statespace search for:
    never claim             + (p0)
    assertion violations    + (if within scope of claim)
    acceptance   cycles     + (fairness disabled)
    invalid end states  - (disabled by never claim)

State-vector 28 byte, depth reached 13, errors: 0
        9 states, stored (11 visited)
        2 states, matched
       13 transitions (= visited+matched)
        0 atomic steps
hash conflicts:         0 (resolved)

Stats on memory usage (in Megabytes):
    0.000   equivalent memory usage for states (stored*(State-vector + overhead))
    0.288   actual memory usage for states
  128.000   memory used for hash table (-w24)
    0.534   memory used for DFS stack (-m10000)
  128.730   total actual memory usage


unreached in init
    (0 of 12 states)
unreached in claim p0
    _spin_nvr.tmp:14, state 20, "-end-"
    (1 of 20 states)

pan: elapsed time 0 seconds
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**STRONG UNTIL**

Its *formal definition* is:

> M, s<sub>k</sub> ⊨ ϕ U ψ
>
> <->
>
> ∃ j ∈ N .
>
> 1. (j ≥ k) ∧
> 2. ∀ i ∈ N . ((k ≤ i < j) ⇒ (<s<sub>i</sub>, s<sub>i+1</sub>> ∈ R<sub>t</sub>)) ∧
> 3. (M, s<sub>j</sub> ⊨ ψ) ∧
> 4. ∀ i ∈ N . ((k ≤ i < j) ⇒ (M, s<sub>i</sub> ⊨ ϕ))
>
> where
>
> - M is the Kripke Structure
> - R<sub>t</sub> is the transition relation

Explanation:

- Conditions *(1)-(2)* enforce the sequence of states (s<sub>k</sub>, s<sub>k+1</sub>, ..., s<sub>j</sub>, ...) to be a valid execution path of the transition system over which the *ltl* formula can be evaluated.
- Condition *(3)* forces `ψ` to hold in s<sub>j</sub>.
- Condition *(4)* forces `ϕ` to hold in *any* state s<sub>i</sub> that lies along the path from s<sub>k</sub> *(included)* up to s<sub>j</sub> *(excluded)*.

Since an implication with a `false` premise is always `true`, the *logical implication* inside condition *(4)* is trivially *satisfied* for any `i` that lies outside of the range `[k, j)`. Whenever `j` is picked to be equal to `k`, as in your question, the range `[k, j) = [k, k)` is empty and any choice of `i` lies outside said interval. In this case, regardless of the fact `M, s ⊨ ϕ` holds *(or not)* for some `s`, condition *(4)* is trivially satisfied for any choice of `i` and it no longer imposes any constraint over the execution path (s<sub>k</sub>, s<sub>k+1</sub>, ..., s<sub>j</sub>, ...). In other words, when `j = k` condition *(4)* no longer provides any meaningful contribution to the verification of property `ϕ U ψ` over the state s<sub>k</sub>.

---

***WEAK UNTIL***

The difference among *weak until*, hereby denoted with `ϕ W ψ`, and *strong until* is that *weak until* is also satisfied by any execution path s.t. `G (ϕ ∧ ¬ψ)`, whereas *strong until* compels `F ψ`.

---

**EXAMPLE ANALYSIS**

The property **p0**

```
[] ((state == Reverse) U (state != Reverse))
```

requires **p1**

```
((state == Reverse) U (state != Reverse))
```

to hold in each and every state of your system. I will break down **p1** in two components for clarity, and define **ϕ** to be equal `state == Reverse` and **ψ** to be equal `state != Reverse` (note: `ϕ <-> !ψ`).

Let's assume, to simplify things, that your system is comprised by the following three states:

- **s_0**: a regular state, which also happens to be the **initial state**
- **s_1**: a reverse state
- **s_2**: the final state

In order for **p0** to hold, **p1** must hold for each of these states.

- in state **s_0** the property **ψ** holds, therefore **p1** holds too for `j` equal *0*.
- in state **s_1** the property **ψ** is `false`. However, we have that **ϕ** holds in **s_1** and **ψ** holds in **s_2** which is its immediate, and only, successor. So property **p1** holds in **s_1**.
- in state **s_2** the property **ψ** is `true`, so **p1** is again trivially satisfied.

---

Comment: Thanks! Can you give the link for where you found that definition? What exactly are `R_t()` and `M`? And how does `for all i < j` imply that the set of `i` can include the empty set? I would think that 'for all i < j' would mean the set of all states from 0 up to state `j-1`.

Comment: I think my main confusion is that I can only find until operator definitions, not strong until. For example, Page 18 of [this](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/edu/year/2009/course/TDA956/TH/l05.html?18) link is not the strong until definition since it requires p to be true for all time steps up until q becomes true, right?