# Is "true U Φ" a valid Computation Tree Logic formula?

Tags: model, logic, grammar, verification, ctl

I'm taking a course on computer-aided verification, and we are just starting to cover Computational Tree Logic after covering Linear Temporal Logic. My lecture has said that ◇Φ ≡ "true U Φ" is valid CTL, whereas □Φ is not valid CTL. I agree with the second part, because a CTL formula is a Φ and the rules for Φ do not include □Φ. But they also don't include ◇Φ or "true U Φ" - only the rules for Ψ include those, and the rules for Φ state that any Ψ must be preceded by ∃ or ∀, and neither ◇Φ or "true U Φ" are. Wikipedia seems to agree with me on this.

Has he just made a mistake, or am I missing something here? [Image of the rules for CTL we have been given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTD3g.png)

Answer (score 0):

*I would dare say that none of those formulas belong to CTL. Perhaps there might have been a misunderstanding, it would be worth contacting your lecturer privately asking about this issue (in a polite manner).*

---

Let me define a mapping between your notation and the one I've been taught.

```
◇ := F ~ eventually
□ := G ~ globally
◯ := X ~ next
∀ := A ~ necessarily
∃ := E ~ possibly
```

The LTL formula `◇ϕ` (`Fϕ`) states that `ϕ` is *necessarily going to hold in the future*. The corresponding CTL formulation would be `∀◇ϕ` (`AFϕ`).

The LTL formula `□ϕ` (`Gϕ`) states that `ϕ` is *globally holding forever*. The corresponding CTL formulation would be `∀□ϕ` (`AGϕ`).

The **[CTL until operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45729772/using-until-operator-in-spin-ltl-formula/45732502#45732502)** can appear in one of two forms:

- `∀(ϕ1 U ϕ2)`: in all possible execution paths, `ϕ1` holds until `ϕ2` holds *(at least once)*.
- `∃(ϕ1 U ϕ2)`: in at least one execution path, `ϕ1` holds until `ϕ2` holds *(at least once)*.

[image]

See also: [CTL operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37516092/how-can-i-change-these-into-ctl-spec-in-nusmv-model/37551933#37551933).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, and I agree, it definitely looks like the lecturer made a mistake.

Comment: what do you mean? He said that ϕ1 U ϕ2 is valid CTL, and you said that ϕ1 U ϕ2 can only appear in CTL in ∀(ϕ1 U ϕ2) or ∃(ϕ1 U ϕ2), so surely he is mistaken in saying that ϕ1 U ϕ2 alone is valid CTL?