# NuSMV CTL specification

Tags: nusmv, ctl

I have started learning NuSMV these days. I have this code:

```
 MODULE main

 VAR

 state: {a,b,c,d,e};   
 ASSIGN

 init(state) := a; 

 next(state) := case

            (state = a)  : b;

            (state = b)  : c;

            (state = c)  : d;

            (state = d)  : e;                   

            TRUE:Stages;

       esac;
```

I want to verify that every time we are in the state "a" the next state will be the state "b". which one is the correct (even if I tried both of them and  they give me both of them true):

```
check_ctlspec -p "AG (state=a -> AX state=b)"

check_ctlspec -p "AF (state=a -> AX state=b)"

check_ctlspec -p "AF (state=a -> AF state=b)"  

check_ctlspec -p "AF (state=a -> state=b)"
```

My second question is: In the model above there is no a transition from the state "d" to the state "a" but when I verify this using

```
check_ctlspec -p "AF (state=d -> AX state=a)"
```

the result was true. Why is this the case?

Comment: What is `Stages`?

Comment: Sorry but I mean state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, let me rename `state` with `my_var` in your model. This avoids confusing the actual state of the automaton with the `state` variable you have introduced.

---

- `AG (my_var = a -> AX my_var = b)`

> In every state of every possible execution, if `my_var` is equal to `a` then it must be necessarily the case that in the next state`my_var` is equal to `b`.

This **is** the property you want to verify.

---

- `AF (my_var=a -> AX my_var=b)`

> Sooner or later, if `my_var` is equal to `a` then it must be necessarily the case that in the next state`my_var` is equal to `b`.

Notice that an **implication** is **true** in two cases:

- when the premise is true and the conclusion is true, or
- when the premise is false

So the implication is trivially made true by any state for which the premise `my_var=a` is not verified, that is, any state other than the initial state. Since you use `AF`, you require the implication to be verified only on (at least) one state for each possible execution path.

In a sense, this is *"too weak"* with respect to what you want to verify.

---

- `AF (my_var=a -> AF my_var=b)`

> Sooner or later, if `my_var` is equal to `a` then it must be necessarily the case at some point in the future (wrt. the state in which `my_var` is equal to `a`) `my_var` becomes equal to `b`.

Similar as previous one, this is even weaker because it does not even specify at what point `my_var` becomes equal to `b`.

---

- `AF (my_var=a -> my_var=b)`

Notice that the implication `(my_var=a -> my_var=b)` is only true when `my_var=a` is false, because `my_var` cannot be con-temporarily assigned to both `a` and `b`. Nevertheless, this condition is verified by any state other than the initial state, so again the property is trivially verified.

---

- `AF (my_var=d -> AX my_var=a)`

Again, this condition is too weak because you are using `AF` and not `AG`. The implication is made true by any state for which `my_var != d`, so it is sufficient for the whole property to be verified.

---

I would invite you to take a look to this [stack-overflow Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37516092/how-can-i-change-these-into-ctl-spec-in-nusmv-model?rq=1) or to [these slides](http://www.patricktrentin.com/pages/fm2018.html) for learning more about the tool and the language.